# Problem with creating foreign key which refers to a composited primary key parent

Tags: mysql

In the mysql code I pasted, the second foreign actor_id_FK cannot be added with error (1215 cannot add foreign key constraint). Where is the problem?

```
create table castings
(
    movieid int,
    actorid int,
    primary key (movieid, actorid)
);

create table movies
(
    id int primary key
);

create table actors
(
    id int primary key
);

alter table movies
add constraint movies_id_FK
foreign key (id) references castings(movieid);

alter table actors
add constraint actors_id_FK
foreign key (id) references castings(actorid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your concept of foreign key backwards.  The definition goes in the *other* table, not where the primary key is defined.  So:

```
alter table castings add constraint fk_castings_movie_id
    foreign key (movieid) references movies(id);
```